# UFW Limit does not appear to work

Tags: ssh, security, firewall, ufw

I have my ssh port changed to XXX. Then I did

```
ufw limit XXX/tcp
```

However, when I try to login, after 5/6 failed attempts I get thrown back to prompt, but I can try again. Is that supposed to be the way it works?

Comment: The example in the `man` page is `ufw limit ssh/tcp`

Comment: @jasonwryan, it says it will deny IP who tried connecting >6 times in the last 30sec. But I can keep trying?

Comment: Did you try with `ssh/tcp`? Is ufw running?

Comment: @jasonwryan, But I changed the port to XXX (a number of course, just dont think I should declare what port I use here :)). So I think I should be using `LIMIT XXX/tcp` instead of `LIMIT ssh/tcp`?

Comment: Yes: I read your question. My reading of the man page is that it limits the _service_ irrespective of the port that it listens on. It can't hurt to try it, can it?

Comment: Just did that `sudo ufw limit ssh`. I can keep trying even within that 30sec interval. Do I need to restart some thing? I do get `Permission denied (publickey,password).` after every 6 tries

Comment: `sudo ufw limit ssh/tcp` - please read the man page...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your description correctly, you're typing `ssh myserver.example.com` and making a few failed attempts, and getting your local prompt back. That is still one TCP connection, so it counts for one against `ufw limit` (the firewall doesn't know anything about authentication attempts, it works at a lower level). You need to make 6 separate ssh connections within 30 seconds to trigger the limit.

Comment: Oh I got it now. Is it possible to limit the user to try 3 times (not the TCP connections). Perhaps I need denyhosts for that? Is there an alternative (just for my information)

Comment: @jiewmeng The number of permitted authentication failures in one SSH connection has to be managed by the SSH daemon, it can't be managed at the TCP level. Set `MaxAuthTries` in `sshd_config`.